# How to capture two substrings from html text?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
data-event-title="Yuichi Sugita* vs Adrian Mannarino">
                              <span class="odds-container">
                                                             <b class="odds">1/12</b>
                                                                     </a>
```

And I would like to capture `Yuichi Sugita` and `1/12`. For that I created the following regex:
`ata-event-title="(.+)".+ class="odds">(.+)<`
which has two capture groups in parenthesis (when I use them separately they work fine), but the problem is that the `.+` in between them does not work as expected.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It "does not work as expected" because you should use something else than regex for  this job.

Comment: Like what? And why?

Comment: Like an HTML parser. [That's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4607733)!

Comment: Anyway, [`.+?`](https://regex101.com/r/V74R87/1) will "work", see http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy

Comment: I'm using Python

Comment: `.+?` does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of dots is "greedy" so they capture as much as they possibly can (and you don't actually want that in this case).

You can change the capture group quantifiers to be "lazy", but it will be more efficient to use negated character classes (syntax `[^character]`) for your capture groups.

The dot between your two capture groups is fine to be "greedy" because it will be halted when it encounters `class="odds">` anyhow.

Assuming you have linebreaks as your sample input shows, your dot will stop on newline characters unless you use the `s` flag with your pattern.  Use this:

```
r"data-event-title=\"([^*]+).*class=\"odds\">([^<]+)"s
```

This will capture:

1. the substring that follows `data-event-title="` ending just before the first occurrence of `*`.
2. the substring that follows `class="odds">` ending just before the first `<` is found.

Here is the Python [regex pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/pAH1Pm/2).

---

If you want the full `data-event-title` attribute value, this will capture `Yuichi Sugita* vs Adrian Mannarino`:

```
r"data-event-title=\"([^\"]+).*class=\"odds\">([^<]+)"s
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture text inside `data-event-title=""` and `1/12` then use regex
`data\-event\-title\=\"(.+?)\"[^\0]*class\=\"odds\".*\>(.+?)\<`
https://regex101.com/r/4loeLv/1

Or

If you want to capture first person's name inside `data-event-title=""` then
`data\-event\-title\=\"(.+?) vs.*?\"[^\0]*class\=\"odds\".*\>(.+?)\<`
https://regex101.com/r/4loeLv/2

Comment: why do I need to put `[^\0]*`?

Comment: In the given text there so many different characters and this could be anything (including `\s`,`\t`,`\n`,`\r`) except `null = \0`.

Answer (score 0):

I used **alternation** with the *vertical bar* or *pipe symbol* (|). [read more here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

This regex does what you want:

```
>(.*)<|data-event-title="([^*]*.).*"
```

See the saved regex here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/r909CQ/1)